# Treeview: How to set values in a specific row where row contains "x" value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a treeview with the following columns:

```
self.columns = ("Name", "Status", "Activity")
```

This treeview is updated depending on the socket message and client name it receives. If the program receives "NAME:", it will insert a new row in the treeview with the client name placed under the "Name" column. Else if it's "CLOSED:", the "Status" and "Activity" columns where client name given is located will be updated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as tick
import socket
from threading import Thread

class GUI2(cust.CTk): #second window, not the root
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):

        self.PORT = a
        self.SERVER = b
        self.ADDRESS = c
        self.FORMAT = d
        self.host = e

        self.master2 = cust.CTkToplevel()
        self.columns = ("name", "status", "activity")

        self.clientlist = tick.Treeview(self.clientframe, columns = self.columns, show = "tree")
        self.clientlist.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")

        self.clientlist.column("#0", minwidth = 0, width = 10, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("name", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("status", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("activity", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)
        
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.initreceiver)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def initreceiver(self):

        try:
            while True:

                self.message = self.host.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)

                if "NAME:" in self.message:
                    x = self.message.replace("NAME:", "") #removes "NAME:" to get the clientname

                    self.clientlist.insert("", cust.END, iid = x, values = x) #inserts new row and display only client name; 
            #also sets iid the same as the client name for reference

                elif "CLOSED:" in self.message:
                    x = self.message.replace("CLOSED", "") #remove "CLOSED:" to get clientname

                    self.clientlist.set(x, "Status", "Eyes are closed") #set "Status" column with the new value
                    self.clientlist.set(x, "Activity", "Eyes are closed") #set "Activity" column with the new value

        except Exception:

            print (traceback.format_exc())
```

Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Personal Programs\Python\Lobby + Tracking\mainmenu.py", line 438, in initreceiver
    self.clientlist.set(x, "status", "Eyes are closed")
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1459, in set
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "set", item, column, value)
_tkinter.TclError: Item :Maikz not found #Maikz is the example client name sent
```

It looks like `.set()` method needs item value for the first argument, but I don't know what to put; I'm learning Treeview for the first time.

I need to be able to set the "Status" and "Activity" cells' values where their "Name" value matches the client name. Any advice or alternative solution is appreciated.

Comment: The error simply states that there is no item called `:Maikz` in your treeview, so the treeview doesn't know for which row to update the value of the column

Comment: `x = self.message.replace("CLOSED", "")` should be `x = self.message.replace("CLOSED:", "")`.  But suggest to use `action, name = self.message.split(":")` and then use `action` in `if` checking and `name` as the row ID.

Comment: @acw1668 that doesn't guarantee that the message exists in the children of the treeview however, so it's error prone to use `set` like this

Comment: @oskros I just point out that OP extracts wrong name.  Even the correct name exists, OP code still has issue.

Comment: @acw1668 Well, it turns out it was the missing ":" which caused the error. The program works now, thanks!

That said, can you please expand on >`use action, name = self.message.split(":")` and then use `action` in `if` checking and `name` as the row ID. I've already set the client name as the row IID every time a new row is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @acw1668, it turns out the cause of the error was a spelling mistake; in `x = self.message.replace("CLOSED", "")` a `:` was missing.

To set the values of "Status" and "Activity" where the "Name" value is the same as the client name, the code is as follows:

```
elif "CLOSED:" in self.message:
    x = self.message.replace("CLOSED:", "") 
    self.clientlist.set(x, "Status", "Eyes are closed") 
    self.clientlist.set(x, "Activity", "Eyes are closed")
```

where x is the client name and is also the item iid as previously set in the line `self.clientlist.insert("", cust.END, iid = x, values = x)` when inserting a new row.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment, you can split the received message into `action` and `name` and use `action` in if checking and `name` as the row ID:

```py
def initreceiver(self):
    try:
        while True:
            self.message = self.host.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)
            action, name = self.message.split(":")
            if action == "NAME":
                self.clientlist.insert("", cust.END, iid=name, values=name)
            elif action == "CLOSED":
                self.clientlist.set(name, "status", "Eyes are closed")
                self.clientlist.set(name, "activity", "Eyes are closed")
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I'll use this code to further improve the program.