# How to fix image not appearing in Treeview; only text appears?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Treeview that updates its values depending on the socket message and client name it receives; after resolving [the previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546782/treeview-how-to-set-values-in-a-specific-row-where-row-contains-x-value), I've tried setting an **image** (e.g. redlight.png, greenlight.png, blacklight.png) to "Activity" column when either "CLOSED:", "AWAKE:", or "NFD:" message is received.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as tick
import socket
from threading import Thread
from PIL import ImageTk as itk
import PIL.Image
from tkinter import PhotoImage

class GUI2(cust.CTk): #second window, not the root
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):

        self.PORT = a
        self.SERVER = b
        self.ADDRESS = c
        self.FORMAT = d
        self.host = e

        self.master2 = cust.CTkToplevel()
        self.columns = ("name", "status", "activity")

        self.clientlist = tick.Treeview(self.clientframe, columns = self.columns, show = "tree")
        self.clientlist.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")

        self.clientlist.column("#0", minwidth = 0, width = 10, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("name", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("status", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)
        self.clientlist.column("activity", minwidth = 0, width = 140, stretch = False)

        self.red = PhotoImage(file = "redlight.png")
        self.green = PhotoImage(file = "greenlight.png")
        self.black = PhotoImage(file = "blacklight.png")
        
        self.thread = Thread(target = self.initreceiver)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def initreceiver(self):

        try:
            while True:

                self.message = self.host.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)

                if "NAME:" in self.message:
                    x = self.message.replace("NAME:", "") #removes "NAME:" to get the clientname

                    self.clientlist.insert("", cust.END, iid = x, values = x) #inserts new row and display only client name; 
            #also sets iid the same as the client name for reference

                elif "CLOSED:" in self.message:
                    x = self.message.replace("CLOSED", "") #remove "CLOSED:" to get clientname

                    self.clientlist.set(x, "Status", "Eyes are closed") #set "Status" column with the new value
                    self.clientlist.set(x, "Activity", self.red) #set "Activity" column with the picture of a red light

                elif "AWAKE:" in self.message:

                    x = self.message.replace("AWAKE:", "")

                    self.clientlist.set(x, "status", "Eyes are open")
                    self.clientlist.set(x, "activity", self.green) #set "Activity" column with the picture of a green light

                elif "NFD:" in self.message:

                    x = self.message.replace("NFD:", "")

                    self.clientlist.set(x, "status", "No Face Detected")
                    self.clientlist.set(x, "activity", self.black) #set "Activity" column with the picture of a black light

        except Exception:

            print (traceback.format_exc())
```

I've also tried using the following code for getting the image:

```
    self.temp = PIL.Image.open("redlight.png")
    self.red = itk.PhotoImage(self.temp)

    self.temp2 = PIL.Image.open("greenlight.png")
    self.green = itk.PhotoImage(self.temp2)

    self.temp3 = PIL.Image.open("blacklight.png")
    self.black = itk.PhotoImage(self.temp3)
```

However, in both code instances, the image doesn't get displayed; instead, the Treeview displays a text labeled ["pyimage2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvzEC.jpg). From further testing, it looks like "pyimage2" refers to green light image, "pyimage1" for red, and "pyimage3" for black.

No traceback errors are displayed in the terminal; the program detects the image file within the same folder but for some reason they're not able to display it in the Treeview. Any help or alternative solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot put an image in columns other than the *tree* column ("#0").  You need to use `image` option to put the image in the *tree* column.

Comment: @acw1668 It says:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Personal Programs\Python\Lobby + Tracking\mainmenu.py", line 477, in initreceiver
    self.clientlist.set(x, "#0", self.green)
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1459, in set
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "set", item, column, value)
_tkinter.TclError: Display column #0 cannot be set`

I've also tried to put **image** in the following code: `self.clientlist.set(x, "activity", image = self.green)`. An error occurs:

Comment: @acw1668 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Personal Programs\Python\Lobby + Tracking\mainmenu.py", line 477, in initreceiver
    self.clientlist.set(x, "activity", image = self.green)
TypeError: Treeview.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image'

Comment: You need to use `self.clientlist.item(x, image=...)`.